# How to record video (1080p 30fps) from raspberry pi camera and stream the 'recording in progress' file simultaneously?

Tags: gstreamer, recording

0

The objective I am trying to achieve is streaming 1080p video from Raspberry pi camera and record the video simultaneously.

I tried recording the http streaming as source but didn't work on 30fps. A lot of frames were missing and almost got 8fps only.

As a second approach, I am trying to record the file directly from camera and then streaming the "recording in progress/buffer" file. For the same I am trying to use GStreamer. Please suggest if this is good option or should I try any other?

For Recording using GStreamer I used

gst-launch-1.0 -v v4l2src device=/dev/video0 ! capsfilter caps="video/x-raw,width=1920,height=1080,framerate=30/1" !
videoflip method=clockwise ! videoflip method=clockwise ! videoconvert ! videorate ! x264enc! avimux ! filesink location=test_video.h264
Result : recorded video shows 1080p and 30fps but frames are dropping heavily.

For Streaming the video buffer I have used UDP in Gstreamer as,

gst-launch-1.0 -v v4l2src device=/dev/video0 !  capsfilter caps="video/x-raw,width=640,height=480,framerate=30/1" ! x264enc ! queue ! rtph264pay ! udpsink host=192.168.5.1 port=8080
Result : No specific errors on terminal but can't get stream on vlc.

Please suggest the best method here.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's already asked twice on a better fitting place  [1](https://superuser.com/q/1432194/172747) [2](https://superuser.com/q/1431889/172747)

Comment: but where I get my answer...any link??